# String is truncated when I read data using Pandas library

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a dataframe in .csv format. I have a column  which has some cells that have data in a string which is very long (upto >5000 characters). When I read the data from that cell, I noticed that the data is truncated to around 1385 characters only.

I have searched around and do "pd.set_option" as well as read the column in the str format but it doesn't help.

```py
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
df=pd.read_csv(path,dtype={"test":"str"})
df.to_csv(output_path)
```

How can I do to extract this data without losing characters?

- Try to set option for Pandas library: `pd.set_option("display.max_colwidth", None)`
- Try to read the data in str format
- Try to export the file immediately after reading by Pandas

Comment: Are you certain that the data is gone after reading & writing with `pandas`, and that it is not just a display issue - that the display cuts off the data (for ease of display)?

Comment: how does one strum a string? Except, of course, a physical one :P

Comment: "strum" I mean is "truncated"- I am quite not familiar with programming term, lol

Comment: I do a simple script to check, I do read data by Pandas then write it into a file right after that. I do compare the content of those cells and realize it only can read/write 1385 characters from ~5.3k characters

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```py
df.to_csv(output_path, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

`quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL` will surround your strings in quotes to prevent special characters from causing truncations.

Comment: thanks for help. I think my string contains many "|" which makes this issue. Is there any way for me to read_csv with the quoting like this for output? I try it for read_csv(path, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL but there is an error about invalid syntax.

Comment: You can use the csv module `reader = csv.reader(file_object, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)`